# Simple Form Isn't Working Anymore

Tags: php, post, email-validation

This simple `POST` form has stopped working.  This form uses `jqueryfunctions.js` and the attached PHP code.  This form was working up until a month or so ago - nothing changed in the code.  When using this form it does not send, it only returns the error "Not Send" message.

PHP version is 5.2.9.  Any help is very much appreciated - I am at my wits end here!

#### PHP code:

```
<?php
if(!$_POST) exit;
 
$values2 = array ('email2','prodLink','prodTitle2','offer');
$required2 = array('email2','prodLink','prodTitle2','offer');
 
$your_email2 = "sales@jimlaabsmusic.com";
$email_subject2 = "JLM.com Make An Offer";
$email_content2 = "Best Price:\n";
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];


foreach($values2 as $value2){
  if(in_array($value2,$required2)){
    if( empty($_POST['email2']) ) { 
        echo '<span class="response2">Use a valid email!</span>'; 
        exit; 
    }
    if(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email2)) {
        echo '<span class="response2">Use a valid email!</span>';
        exit;
    }
    $email_content2 .= $value2.': '.$_POST[$value2]."\n\n";
    
  }
}
 
if(mail($your_email2,$email_subject2,$email_content2,'From: '.$email2)) {
    echo '<span class="response2sent">Sent!</span>'; 
} else {
    echo 'No Send!';
}
?>
```

Here is the form HTML code:

```
div id="bestPriceOutter">
        <a onclick="ShowHideEmail('#bestPriceBox','#tradeSave'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/other/bestoffer.png" width="208" height="25" alt="Get the best price on this product! Please enter your email" border="0" class="jqueryHighlight" /></a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="bestPriceBox">
            <form action="php/bestprice-email.php" method="post" id="bestPriceEmail">        
                <label for="email2">Your Email</label> <input id="email2" name="email2" class="text" size="30" /> 
                <label for="offer">Your Best Offer</label> <input id="offer" name="offer" class="text" size="30" />                
                <input id="prodLink" name="prodLink" class="text" value="" type="hidden" />
                <input id="prodTitle2" name="prodTitle2" class="text" value='{TXT_PRODTITLE}' type="hidden" />
                <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit2" class="submit" />   
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML form code?

Comment: Is your mail server working?

Comment: Mail server is working.

Comment: Checked your PHP error logs?

Comment: Have you tried logging the values being used by your call to `mail()`?

Comment: There is nothing in the PHP logs for today or in the past where it seems not to be working.  Question though - I believe someone updated our SSL cert around the time this stopped working, could that be a cause of this issue at all?

Comment: I have now disabled all but the one contact form that isn't working.  It seems as if neither the $_POST or $_GET function is working on our server.  Help?!